# UPDATE table with SELECT from another but with a field being SUM(someField)

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically I have something like this:

```
UPDATE
    Table
SET
    Table.col1 = other_table.col1,
FROM
    Table
INNER JOIN
    other_table
ON
    Table.id = other_table.id
```

The problem is that I would like to update `col1` with the select being like:

```
SELECT SUM(col1) FROM other_table WHERE Table.id = other_table.id AND period > 2011
```

### Edit

Correct Answer:

```
UPDATE bestall  
INNER JOIN (SELECT bestid,SUM(view) as v,SUM(rawView) as rv 
                           FROM beststat 
                           WHERE period > 2011 GROUP BY bestid) as t1 
ON bestall.bestid = t1.bestid
SET view = t1.v, rawview = t1.rv
```

Comment: are you sure? other queries work without any prolbems, also it isn't listed here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use aggregates directly in a `set` clause. One way around that is a subquery:

```
update  your_table as yt
left join 
        (
        select  id
        ,       count(*) as cnt
        from    other_table
        where   period < 4
        group by
                id       
        ) as ot
on      yt.id = ot.id 
set     col1 = coalesce(ot.cnt,0)
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20a33/8)

Comment: Your query is pretty similar to mine, but both gives Syntax error near: `from bestall left join [...]` @andomar

Comment: it is pretty strange even this simpler syntax gives error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262300/strange-synrax-error-from-update-with-a-join

Comment: Oh, it's MySQL!  That's a different syntax, and a different `isnull`.  Answer updated.  My comment on @MGA's answer is invalid too.

Comment: damn andomar :D i was losing my mind i even opened the other question. Anyway regarding coalesce: just do an INNER JOIN, so in the case that there aren't both records the update isn't performed and it's good because the default value is already 0

Comment: even the SQL Fiddle is giving syntax errors like my mysql anyway

Comment: Looks like the `set` goes at the end, answer and fiddle updated again.  Update syntax is a bit tricky!

Comment: I wonder how did you find that error so quickly... that wasn't so easy