# Syntax error "near FROM" when using UPDATE with JOIN in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

```
UPDATE bestall SET view = t1.v, rawview = t1.rv 

FROM bestall INNER JOIN beststat as t1

ON bestall.bestid = t1.bestid
```

this query gives syntax error near

```
 'FROM bestall INNER JOIN beststat as t1 ON bestall.bestid = t1.bestid' at line 3
```

any reasons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That isn't valid MySQL syntax. It *is* valid in MS SQL Server, however.  For MySQL, use:

```
UPDATE 
  bestall
  JOIN beststat AS t1 ON bestall.bestid = t1.bestid 
SET view = t1.v, rawview = t1.rv
```

MySQL requires the update tables to come before the `SET` clause. See the [MySQL `UPDATE` syntax reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) for full details.

Comment: @yes123 Sorry - just made some updates.  I copied my answer from a comment on one of your questions from a little bit ago, but this was a different query.

Comment: you have got the point anyway... the problem is that the other query still has syntax errors http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261977/update-table-with-select-from-another-but-with-a-field-being-sumsomefield

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
UPDATE bestall INNER JOIN beststat as t1
ON bestall.bestid = t1.bestid SET view = t1.v, rawview = t1.rv
```